# `moment` library vs angular `Pipe` in handling Date formatting

Tags: javascript, angular, date, pipe

I am using both `moment` library and angular `pipe` to handle Date object (formatting).
The problem I have found is the difference in interpretation of the date format string.

I have java script Date object called `formDate` =`Fri Oct 20 2023 08:30:00 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time)` and I use the format string `'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'` then:

- Using angular pipe - expected result

The code: `this.datePipe.transform(formDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm');` produces `'2023-10-20 08:30'`

- Using moment library - incorrect result

moment library code: `moment(formDate).format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm');` produces `'2023-10-Fr 08:30'`

Why there is discrepancy between them. Which one should I use to handle the dates.

If I use the format string  'yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm' moment library works as expected (produces output of `'2023-10-20 08:30'`) and pipe does not work (produces output of `'2023-10-DD 08:30'`)

Comment: There is no standard for formatting tokens, different libraries use different tokens. Some only slightly, others entirely. The more important question is why are you using two different libraries for formatting in the same project?

Comment: Excellent question. I converted my code to use one library moment. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For moment.js, you'll need to use `DD` instead of `dd`. Lowercase represent days of the week, explaining the result you are getting.

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: So I need to maintain two formatting strings ? one for moment library and one for angular pipe? That does not seem to be a clean thing to do. Is this a bug in one of the libraries.

Comment: Agreed that it isn't the cleanest of solutions, but a workaround might involve mutating how the two underlying libraries format dates? That looks like the bigger of two evils.